# Javascript Rock Paper Scissors Game Syntax Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm working on a rock paper scissor game and I'm having an issue with displaying the winner. I think it has to do with my syntax, but I've been looking at it for too long and I need some fresh eyes. All of my code is here 
`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/akosuak/L03spu70/1/.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: @verygreen what error are you getting when you inspect in the console?

Comment: Chrome complains about a missing )

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I'm not getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showResult()
```

Isn't closed correctly its missing a }

//EDITED

I noticed that you never set the userChoice to a new value so i changed that for you.

The other person his solution was pretty cool using regex but i think that's not really needed in my opinion.

the way he changed your syntax was pretty cool and i think you should check that out some more.

here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/L03spu70/8/

I didn't add the syntax changes but it works now

Comment: I fixed the }, but it's still not giving me the correct answers

Comment: The way your if and else are structured break the function

Comment: Also for some reason the users choice is always rock XD

Comment: Edited my answer with a new fiddle hope this works for you

Comment: @verygreen use a code linter to find syntax errors...either in your IDE or an online version. Simple syntax problems shouldn't end up here as questions when there are numerous tools to find them with

Answer (score 0):

@Bob-Thomas is correct, adding the missing `}` at the end of showResult() seems to resolve the issue:

```js
var $rockButton = $('#rock').text();
var $paperButton = $('#paper').text();
var $scissorsButton = $('#scissor').text();
var $resetButton = $('#reset');
var $resultsText = $('#results-text');

// var rpsArray = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

var userChoice = 'Rock' || 'Paper' || 'Scissors';
var computerChoice = 'Rock' || 'Paper' || 'Scissors';


function setComputerChoice() {
  computerChoice = Math.random();

  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = 'Rock';
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = 'Paper';
  } else {
    computerChoice = 'Scissors';
  }
  $('#computer-text').text(computerChoice);
};

var deactivateButton = function(currentButton) {
  var buttonid = "#" + currentButton;
  var buttons = ['#rock', '#scissor', '#paper'];
  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    if (button != buttonid) {
      $(button).css({
        'visibility': 'hidden'
      })
    };
  });
};


function showResult() {
    if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
      $('#results-text').text('Tie');
    };

    if (userChoice == 'Rock') {
      if (computerChoice == 'Paper')
        $('#results-text').text('Paper Wins!!');
    } else {
      if (computerChoice == 'Scissors') {
        $('#results-text').text('Rock Wins!!');
      };

      if (userChoice == 'Scissors') {
        if (computerChoice == 'Rock') {
          $('#results-text').text('Rock Wins!!');
        } else {
          if (computerChoice == 'Paper') {
            $('#results-text').text('Scissors Wins!!');
          }
        }
      }

    }
  } //end of function

$(function() {
  $('#rock').on('click', function() {
    $('#user-text').text('Rock');
    deactivateButton(this.id);
    setComputerChoice();
    showResult();
  })

  $('#scissor').on('click', function() {
    $('#user-text').text('Scissors');
    deactivateButton(this.id);
    setComputerChoice();
    showResult();
  })

  $('#paper').on('click', function() {
    $('#user-text').text('Paper');
    deactivateButton(this.id);
    setComputerChoice();
    showResult();
  })

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $('#user-text').text('');
    $('#computer-text').text('');
    $('#results-text').text('');

    $('#rock').css({
      'visibility': 'visible'
    });
    $('#paper').css({
      'visibility': 'visible'
    });
    $('#scissor').css({
      'visibility': 'visible'
    });

  })


})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #5D6377;
  color: #fff;
}
#game-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#rock,
#paper,
#scissor,
#reset {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#rock:hover,
#paper:hover,
#scissor:hover,
#reset:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button-group {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#choice-group {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
#user-choice,
#computer-choice {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
#results {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
#user-text,
#computer-text {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="game-container">

  <div id="button-group">
    <span id="rock">Rock</span>
    <span id="paper">Paper</span>
    <span id="scissor">Scissors</span>
    <span id="reset">Reset</span>
  </div>

  <div id="choice-group">
    <div id="user-choice">
      <h1 id="user-text"></h1>
    </div>

    <div id="computer-choice">
      <h1 id="computer-text"></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="results">
    <h1 id="results-text"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually it doesn't. I clicked through a few options and I got 'Scissor/ Rock' combination and the text said 'Tie'